# How to make an interactive chessboard with movable pieces?

Tags: interactive

I want to make a chessboard with pieces and move those pieces with drag and drop using the mouse, is that possible?

Comment: I am waiting for the question "How to turn off my TV with Mathematica?"

Answer (score 4):

It's [the winner of 2021 one-liner competition](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/11/24/the-winners-of-the-2021-one-liner-competition/), isn't it?

```
Graphics@{Raster@Array[.9^+## &, {8, 8}], 
  MapIndexed[
    Locator[#2 - .5, #] &, {b = {\[WhiteRook], \[WhiteKnight], \[WhiteBishop], \
\[WhiteQueen], \[WhiteKing], \[WhiteBishop], \[WhiteKnight], \[WhiteRook]}, 
     y = Table[\[WhitePawn], 8], 3, , , , y, b}, {2}] /. 3 -> Red}
```